# How to get the page scope id of Facebook when user checkout in my Shopify store?

Tags: facebook, shopify, facebook-messages

Before facebook last update I was using Facebook Send message API by passing user reference. I was getting this information by checking the checkbox during checkout in my store (Shopify) using Facebook.

Now the Facebook Send message API no longer returns recipient_id in the response for message sends that use recipient.user_ref or recipient.phone_number to identify the message recipient.

Now they are using the Page scope id syntax is

```
 recipient": {
"id": "<PSID>"
},
```

i am using [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api) API

How can I get this page scope id?