# how we can get Page-scoped-id from user id in facebook send api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot, shopify-app, facebook-messages

Before facebook last update I was using  Facebook Send message API by passing user reference parameter and getting recipient id in response.

Now the Facebook Send message API not returns recipient_id in the response when we use recipient.user_ref or recipient.phone_number to identify the message recipient.

Now they are using the Page scope id parameter like this

```
recipient": {
"id": "<PSID>"
},
```

How can I get this page scope id? So i can pass this to send api?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49035696/1427878 with different account, or copy&paste …?

Answer (score 1):

Correct, the PSID is no longer returned in the API response for user_ref and phone number sends. You will receive the PSID in the sender.id property of the webhook event when the user responds to the message.